# Generate random JSON structure permutations for a data set

Tags: python, json, permutation

I want to generate many different permutations of JSON structures as a representation of the same data set, preferably without having to hard code the implementation. For example, given the following JSON:

```
{"name": "smith", "occupation": "agent", "enemy": "humanity", "nemesis": "neo"}`
```

Many different permutations should be produced, such as:

- change in name : `{"name":"smith"}- > {"last_name":"smith"}`
- change in order: `{"name":"...","occupation":"..."} -> {"occupation":"...", "name":"..."}`
- change in arrangement: `{"name":"...","occupation":"..."} -> "smith":{"occupation":"..."}`
- change in template: `{"name":"...","occupation":"..."} -> "status": 200, "data":{"name":"...","occupation":"..."}`
- etc.

Currently, the implementation is as follows:

I am using `itertools.permutations` and OrderedDict() to range through the possible key and respective value combinations as well as the order in which they are returned.

```
key_permutations = SchemaLike(...).permutate()

all_simulacrums = []
for key_permutation in key_permutations:
   simulacrums = OrderedDict(key_permutation)
   all_simulacrums.append(simulacrums)
for x in itertools.permutations(all_simulacrums.items()):
    test_data = json.dumps(OrderedDict(p))
    print(test_data)
    assert json.loads(test_data) == data, 'Oops! {} != {}'.format(test_data, data)
```

My problem occurs when I try to implement the permutations of arrangement and template.
I don't know how best to implement this functionality, any suggestions?

Comment: Python `dicts` are unordered collections (JSON objects are unordered too, but I guess this is what you want to test). Use `collections.OrderdDict` instead of plain `dicts´.

Comment: `dict`'s are unordered in python, and `json` objects are implemented like `dicts`

Comment: No, I want to be able to dynamically generate many different permutations of JSON structures in JSON as a representation of the same data set, preferably without having to hard code the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though

Comment: For change in name, how are the valid options going to be specified?

Comment: I would merely specify the valid options in a schema like implementation as is described in this article about python validation with voluptuous [link](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2015/python-schema-validation-voluptuous) another interesting link that I have found while trying to determine a solution [link](http://jsonschema.net/#/editor) ... if i could implement something similar but with randomness implemented as described in my question.

Comment: Let me expound on my question, maybe its brevity is what is causing the disruption.

Comment: @Brad I'm nominating this question for reopening because I think it is an interesting question (you got 4 upvotes) and is salvageable. I would appreciate if you improve it telling us what is the real problem you are trying to solve instead of asking how to implement the solution you devised (this is known as the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: seems like a logical request, I will think about it and try to ascertain a more succinct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For ordering, just use ordered dicts:

```
>>> data = OrderedDict(foo='bar', bacon='eggs', bar='foo', eggs='bacon')
>>> for p in itertools.permutations(data.items()):
...     test_data = json.dumps(OrderedDict(p))
...     print(test_data)
...     assert json.loads(test_data) == data, 'Oops! {} != {}'.format(test_data, data)

{"foo": "bar", "bacon": "eggs", "bar": "foo", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"foo": "bar", "bacon": "eggs", "eggs": "bacon", "bar": "foo"}
{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo", "bacon": "eggs", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo", "eggs": "bacon", "bacon": "eggs"}
{"foo": "bar", "eggs": "bacon", "bacon": "eggs", "bar": "foo"}
{"foo": "bar", "eggs": "bacon", "bar": "foo", "bacon": "eggs"}
{"bacon": "eggs", "foo": "bar", "bar": "foo", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"bacon": "eggs", "foo": "bar", "eggs": "bacon", "bar": "foo"}
{"bacon": "eggs", "bar": "foo", "foo": "bar", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"bacon": "eggs", "bar": "foo", "eggs": "bacon", "foo": "bar"}
{"bacon": "eggs", "eggs": "bacon", "foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}
{"bacon": "eggs", "eggs": "bacon", "bar": "foo", "foo": "bar"}
{"bar": "foo", "foo": "bar", "bacon": "eggs", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"bar": "foo", "foo": "bar", "eggs": "bacon", "bacon": "eggs"}
{"bar": "foo", "bacon": "eggs", "foo": "bar", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"bar": "foo", "bacon": "eggs", "eggs": "bacon", "foo": "bar"}
{"bar": "foo", "eggs": "bacon", "foo": "bar", "bacon": "eggs"}
{"bar": "foo", "eggs": "bacon", "bacon": "eggs", "foo": "bar"}
{"eggs": "bacon", "foo": "bar", "bacon": "eggs", "bar": "foo"}
{"eggs": "bacon", "foo": "bar", "bar": "foo", "bacon": "eggs"}
{"eggs": "bacon", "bacon": "eggs", "foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}
{"eggs": "bacon", "bacon": "eggs", "bar": "foo", "foo": "bar"}
{"eggs": "bacon", "bar": "foo", "foo": "bar", "bacon": "eggs"}
{"eggs": "bacon", "bar": "foo", "bacon": "eggs", "foo": "bar"}
```

The same principle can be applied for key/value permutations:

```
>>> for p in itertools.permutations(data.keys()):
...:     test_data = json.dumps(OrderedDict(zip(p, data.values())))
...:     print(test_data)
...:     
{"foo": "bar", "bacon": "eggs", "bar": "foo", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"foo": "bar", "bacon": "eggs", "eggs": "foo", "bar": "bacon"}
{"foo": "bar", "bar": "eggs", "bacon": "foo", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"foo": "bar", "bar": "eggs", "eggs": "foo", "bacon": "bacon"}
{"foo": "bar", "eggs": "eggs", "bacon": "foo", "bar": "bacon"}
{"foo": "bar", "eggs": "eggs", "bar": "foo", "bacon": "bacon"}
{"bacon": "bar", "foo": "eggs", "bar": "foo", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"bacon": "bar", "foo": "eggs", "eggs": "foo", "bar": "bacon"}
{"bacon": "bar", "bar": "eggs", "foo": "foo", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"bacon": "bar", "bar": "eggs", "eggs": "foo", "foo": "bacon"}
{"bacon": "bar", "eggs": "eggs", "foo": "foo", "bar": "bacon"}
{"bacon": "bar", "eggs": "eggs", "bar": "foo", "foo": "bacon"}
{"bar": "bar", "foo": "eggs", "bacon": "foo", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"bar": "bar", "foo": "eggs", "eggs": "foo", "bacon": "bacon"}
{"bar": "bar", "bacon": "eggs", "foo": "foo", "eggs": "bacon"}
{"bar": "bar", "bacon": "eggs", "eggs": "foo", "foo": "bacon"}
{"bar": "bar", "eggs": "eggs", "foo": "foo", "bacon": "bacon"}
{"bar": "bar", "eggs": "eggs", "bacon": "foo", "foo": "bacon"}
{"eggs": "bar", "foo": "eggs", "bacon": "foo", "bar": "bacon"}
{"eggs": "bar", "foo": "eggs", "bar": "foo", "bacon": "bacon"}
{"eggs": "bar", "bacon": "eggs", "foo": "foo", "bar": "bacon"}
{"eggs": "bar", "bacon": "eggs", "bar": "foo", "foo": "bacon"}
{"eggs": "bar", "bar": "eggs", "foo": "foo", "bacon": "bacon"}
{"eggs": "bar", "bar": "eggs", "bacon": "foo", "foo": "bacon"}
```

And so on... You can just use a predefined set of keys/values if you don't need all combinations. You can also use a `for` loop with `random.choice` to flip a coin in order to skip some combinations or use `random.shuffle` at the risk of repeating combinations.

For the template thing I guess you must create a list (or a list of lists if you want nested structures) of different templates and then iterate over it in order to create your data. In order to give a better suggestion we need a more constrained specification of what you want.

Note that there are several libraries that generate test data in Python:

```
>>> from faker import Faker
>>> faker = Faker()
>>> faker.credit_card_full().strip().split('\n')
['VISA 13 digit', 'Jerry Gutierrez', '4885274641760 04/24', 'CVC: 583']
```

[Faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) has several schemas and it is easy to create your own custom fake data providers.

Comment: Cool thanks for the answer, how would you then utilize itertools.permutations to change the field names, template, and arrangement as specified above according to a dict (or by some other method) respectively?

Answer (score 2):

Since the shuffle for the dict order has already been answered, I'll skip that.

I'll add to this answer as new things come to mind.

```
from random import randint
from collections import OrderedDict

#Randomly shuffles the key-value pairs of a dictionary
def random_dict_items(input_dict):
    items = input_dict.items()
    new_dict = OrderedDict()
    for i in items:
        rand = randint(0, 1)
        if rand == 0:
            new_dict[i[0]] = i[1]
        else:
            new_dict[i[1]] = i[0]
    return new_dict
```