# How to generate random json data everytime using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, faker, json-schema-faker

The following code generates random json data:

```
import json 
my_dict = {'foo': 42, 'bar': {'baz': "Hello", 'poo': 124.2}}
    my_json = json.dumps(my_dict)
    print(my_json)
```

How to automate it so that it generates random json data everytime. Know that faker library in python does generate random data. How to combine it with json.

Comment: I think this question and its answers should suffice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547279/generate-random-json-structure-permutations-for-a-data-set

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import json 
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
fake = Faker('en_US')
for _ in range(10):
    my_dict = {    'foo': randint(0, 100),    'bar': {'baz': fake.name(),       'poo': float(random.randrange(155, 389))/100   } }
    print(my_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'foo': 19, 'bar': {'baz': 'Kimberly Robinson', 'poo': 3.33}}
{'foo': 64, 'bar': {'baz': 'Brandon Goodwin', 'poo': 3.55}}
{'foo': 48, 'bar': {'baz': 'David Jacobs', 'poo': 1.74}}
{'foo': 20, 'bar': {'baz': 'John Stout', 'poo': 2.43}}
{'foo': 68, 'bar': {'baz': 'Janet Adams', 'poo': 2.48}}
{'foo': 57, 'bar': {'baz': 'Amy Odonnell', 'poo': 3.34}}
{'foo': 49, 'bar': {'baz': 'Steven Greene', 'poo': 2.34}}
{'foo': 7, 'bar': {'baz': 'Stephen Robinson', 'poo': 1.93}}
{'foo': 32, 'bar': {'baz': 'Joel Wise', 'poo': 3.37}}
{'foo': 33, 'bar': {'baz': 'Stephanie Thompson DDS', 'poo': 2.41}}
```