# (Python) (Json to Excel) Generating random name and ID from Json(Python) to Excel

Tags: python, json, excel

everyone. I'm generating random name and ID from Json (Python) to Excel but there is an issue.

```js
import json 
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
from json2excel import Json2Excel

if __name__ == '__main__':
    json2excel = Json2Excel(head_name_cols=["Random_ID", "Random_UserName"])

fake = Faker('en_US')
for _ in range(10):
    my_dict = {'Random_ID': randint(0, 10000),'User': {'Random_UserName': fake.name(),'age': int(random.randrange(10, 100))} }
    
    print(json2excel.run(my_dict))
```

**and the console output**

```js
PS C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\Python> & C:/Users/chuan/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe c:/Users/chuan/OneDrive/Desktop/Python/1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\1.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(json2excel.run(my_dict))
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\json2excel\j2e.py", line 75, in run
    file_path = self._export_handler(data_list, file_name)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\json2excel\handlers\export_handler.py", line 56, in __call__
    self._add_row(each_dict)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\json2excel\handlers\export_handler.py", line 68, in _add_row
    self._ws.append(row)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packa  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.value = value  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 252, in value
    self._bind_value(value)  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 218, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))ValueError: Cannot convert {'Random_UserName': 'Kristen Schultz', 'age': 97} to Excel
PS C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\Python>
```

I do also see the relative problem down below to helped me get here, but I still stocking at this point,

[(Link) from stack overflow "How to generate random json data everytime using python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948258/how-to-generate-random-json-data-everytime-using-python)

[(pic) The output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzik1.png)

How can I correct?? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using json2excel package you can use the definitely more common package pandas to do the same in a definitely better documented way (json2excel uses Chinese in its docs):

```
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fake = Faker('en_US')
    list_of_my_dicts = []
    for _ in range(10):
        my_dict = {'Random_ID': randint(0, 10000),
                   'User': {'Random_UserName': fake.name(), 'age': int(random.randrange(10, 100))}}

        list_of_my_dicts += [my_dict]

    dataframe = pd.json_normalize(list_of_my_dicts)

    # create excel writer object
    with pd.ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx') as writer:
        # write dataframe to excel
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Output:

| A | ID | User.RandomName | User.age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4577 | Mark Duran | 39 |
| 1 | 360 | Elizabeth Reeves | 82 |
| 2 | 4667 | Jessica Blevins | 63 |
| 3 | 7629 | Michael Allison | 21 |
| 4 | 8392 | Richard Russo | 30 |
| 5 | 9925 | Kevin Maddox | 82 |
| 6 | 3845 | Heidi Thomas | 13 |
| 7 | 3619 | Andrea Thomas | 61 |
| 8 | 9489 | Henry Smith | 26 |
| 9 | 8055 | Dennis Travis | 93 |